# How can I add synonymous recognition in tfidfvectorizer using scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, token, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am using tfidfvectorizer from sklearn.
I wan't to add synonymous vocabulary to the object, to counting the same term finding "house" and "houses" for example. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to add that to preprocessing step to return a common word for all the synonyms. Something like a stemmer.

Comment: Thanks, I have defined my own tokenizer, and pass it as an argument.